# using conditionals in jquery

Tags: jquery, conditional-statements

just trying to tie up a few loose odds and ends here. I have the following code:

```
$(function(){
    // start a counter for new row IDs
    // by setting it to the number
    // of existing rows
    var newRowNum = 2;

    var quantity = 1;
    // bind a click event to the "Add" link
    $("a").bind("click", function() {
        // increment the counter
        newRowNum += 1;

        // get the entire "Add" row --
        // "this" refers to the clicked element
        // and "parent" moves the selection up
        // to the parent node in the DOM
        var addRow = $(this).parent().parent();

        // copy the entire row from the DOM
        // with "clone"
        var newRow = addRow.clone();

        // set the values of the inputs
        // in the "Add" row to empty strings
        //$('input', addRow).val('');
        //$('name', addRow).val('os' + newRowNum);

        // replace the HTML for the "Add" link 
        // with the new row number
        $('td:first-child', newRow).html('<input type="hidden" name="on' + newRowNum + '" value="Recipient Address ' + (newRowNum - 1) + '">Recipient');

        // insert a remove link in the last cell
        $('td:last-child', newRow).html('<a href="" class="remove">Remove<\/a>');

        // loop through the inputs in the new row
        // and update the ID and name attributes

        $('input:hidden', newRow).attr('id','on' + newRowNum ).attr('name','on' + newRowNum );
        $('textarea', newRow).attr('id','os' + newRowNum ).attr('name','os' + newRowNum );

        // insert the new row into the table
        // "before" the Add row

        addRow.before(newRow);

        document.tp01.quantity.value = newRowNum-1;
        quantity += 1;
        // add the remove function to the new row
        $('a.remove', newRow).click(function(){
            $(this).parent().parent().remove();
            document.tp01.quantity.value = quantity-1;
            return false;               
        });

        // prevent the default click
        return false;
    });

});
```

What I am trying to do is use a conditional block here which tests to see if quantity = 6 and if so, not allow the user to add a new row (email recipient). I have tried the following:

```
    if(quantity < 7) {
        addRow.before(newRow);
        };
```

to test if quantity is less than seven (6 max) and only then allow them to add a new row. This does not work.
I have also tried:`if(quantity < 6) {
            quantity += 1;
            };`

to test if the quantity was less than 6 and if so, add one to the value. Otherwise nothing. This does not work.

Basically, what I need to do is, everytime someone adds a row, I need to increment the quantity (which it is now doing correctly) but not allow them to add more than 6 rows (which it is NOT doing correctly).

As always, your help is appreciated.

Dave

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Do you get no rows? Does the condition always evaluate to true? Are you sure the quantity is incrementing properly?

Comment: Also, an example page would be useful.

Comment: What is the difference between quantity and document.tp01.quantity.value? They look like they have different scopes and get set in different places?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try pulling quantity out of the document.ready.

```
var quantity = 0;

$(function()...
```

My guess is that the quantity variable is no longer in scope when you go back into the event handler.

Comment: Ok ... everything seems to be working with the one exception that my quantity value for the hidden field 'quantity' is not decreasing as I remove rows. Well it is, sort of. When I remove two rows, the value only decreases by one and that is a far as it will go. When I add the two rows back in, the value increases, but only by one. 
Can you spot what I have screwed up here.

By the way ... how do I add code back into the comments?

Dave